# Where can I find my role in a Apple Developer Program Team?

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, iphone-developer-program

I want to know if there's a way for me to see what role I have in an Apple developer team. I was trying to create a provisioning profile for a new device we want to test but the create and edit button are disabled. I think it might be a role restriction but I'm not sure. Where can I find that information in the developer portal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After logging in to the Member Center, click people and you will see all roles. If you cannot see this tab, you are a Member.

Answer (score 1):

You are a Member. How do I know? Because if you were an Admin or an Agent, you would see the People tab in the Member Center and you wouldn't be asking this question.